# Using Json.Net, how can I stream a lot of text to a single json property?

Tags: c#, stream, json.net

I need to construct a `JObject` that has a single property that could potentially contain a very large amount of text.  I have this text being read from a stream, but I can't figure out how to write it to a single `JToken`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        // write a lot of random text to the stream
        var docSize = 1024 * 1024;
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < docSize; i++)
        {
            var c = (char) rnd.Next('A', 'Z');
            streamWriter.Write(c);
        }
        streamWriter.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // read from the stream and write a token
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jTokenWriter = new JTokenWriter())
        {
            const int blockSize = 1024;
            var buffer = new char[blockSize];
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var charsRead = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                var str = new string(buffer, 0, charsRead);
                jTokenWriter.WriteValue(str);
            }

            // add the token to an object
            var doc = new JObject();
            doc.Add("Text", jTokenWriter.Token);

            // spit out the json for debugging
            var json = doc.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
            Debug.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a proof of concept.  Of course, in reality, I will be getting the stream from elsewhere (a filestream, for example).  The data could potentially be very large - hundreds of megabytes.  So just working with strings is out of the question.

This example doesn't work.  Only the last block read is left in the token.  How can I write a value to the token and have it append to what was previously written instead of replacing it?

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

To clarify - the text being written is *not* already in json format.  It is closer to human readable text.  It will need to go through the same escaping and formatting that would occur if you wrote a plain string value.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I believe that the answer is "It can't be done".

Really, I think a single JValue of a very large string is something to avoid. I instead broke it up into smaller values stored in a JArray.

If I am wrong, please post a better answer.  Thanks.